# Jquery slideToggle bounces when it hits the height

Tags: jquery, css, slide, bounce

I'm trying to make a slide down menu. The problem is that when it slides down it instantly slides up again as soon at it hits the height of the list that's being slided down.

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

                $(".Mobile-Menu").click(function(){

                $(".Mobile-list").slideToggle("slow");

                });
            });
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="Mobile-Menu">
 <img class="Mobile-Menu" src="menu.png">
 <ul class="Mobile-list">
  <a Id="Mobile-Home" href="#Home-Anchor"><li>Home</li></a>
  <a Id="Mobile-What" href="#What-Anchor"><li>What Is Encryption?</li></a>
  <a Id="Mobile-Test" href="#Test-Anchor"><li>Test It Yourself</li></a>
  <a Id="Mobile-How" href="#How-Anchor"><li>How Does It Work</li></a>
 </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.Mobile-Menu {

    display: block;

    position: fixed;

    top: -3px;

    left: 10px;

    z-index: 75;

    width: 100px;

}


.Mobile-list {

    position: fixed;

            display: none;

    top: 90px;

    left: 20px;

    text-align: left;

    background-color: #1b2021;

    font-size: 22pt;

            padding: 2px;

}
```

If someone could please explain why it would "bounce" then I would be really thankful!

Comment: Sorry, that's not what stood in my code. I fixed it now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have multiple elements with the `Mobile-Menu` class that are nested, the click event bubbles up the DOM and gets triggered multiple times. Stop that by using `.stopPropagation()`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".Mobile-Menu").click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(".Mobile-list").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/vBc7W/)**

Or, just remove the `Mobile-Menu` class from the div and leave it on the image: **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/72TLv/1/)**